# Odoo problems to execute "search" in java

Tags: java, odoo-10

I'm having a problem when we want to execute a search in Odoo's Api in Java.

My code is:

```
    Arrays.asList((Object[])models.execute("execute_kw", Arrays.asList(
            db, uid, pass,
            "res.partner", "search",
            Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(
                    Arrays.asList("is_company", "=", true),
                    Arrays.asList("customer", "=", true)))
        )));
```

And the error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/etc/odoo/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 56, in xmlrpc_return
    result = odoo.http.dispatch_rpc(service, method, params)
  File "/etc/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 118, in dispatch_rpc
    result = dispatch(method, params)
  File "/etc/odoo/odoo/service/model.py", line 38, in dispatch
    res = fn(db, uid, *params)
  File "/etc/odoo/odoo/service/model.py", line 157, in execute_kw
    return execute(db, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw or {})
  File "/etc/odoo/odoo/service/model.py", line 101, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/etc/odoo/odoo/service/model.py", line 164, in execute
    res = execute_cr(cr, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw)
  File "/etc/odoo/odoo/service/model.py", line 153, in execute_cr
    return odoo.api.call_kw(recs, method, args, kw)
  File "/etc/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 687, in call_kw
    return call_kw_model(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "/etc/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 672, in call_kw_model
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: search() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)

    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcStreamTransport.readResponse(XmlRpcStreamTransport.java:197)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcStreamTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcStreamTransport.java:156)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcHttpTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcHttpTransport.java:143)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcSunHttpTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcSunHttpTransport.java:69)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClientWorker.execute(XmlRpcClientWorker.java:56)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:167)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:158)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:147)
    at com.intmpago.springintegration.services.MainBorrar.main(MainBorrar.java:43)
```

I copy this code from the official documentation: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/api_integration.html

Do you know why it is happening?

Comment: The error says here `TypeError: search() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)`

Comment: yes but in the official documentation the example only uses the parameters that I showed in the code

Comment: Since the code in this question is literally a copy-paste from their sample code for "List Records", it sounds like a bug - ping their support team.

Answer (score 0):

```
List ids = asList((Object[])models.execute(
"execute_kw", asList(
    db, uid, password,
    "res.partner", "search",
    asList(asList(
        asList("is_company", "=", true),
        asList("customer", "=", true))),
    new HashMap() {{ put("limit", 1); }})));
```

The second argument is the HashMap giving the number of elements you want to read.